# TYPO3 setup.typoscript configured does not show any results

Tags: php, templates, typo3, typo3-9.x

It seems that my `setup.typoscript` is not working properly.

The error:

> The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with **typeNum=0** configured.

my setup.typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HALLO
```

Include in the backend are configured and shows the extension so sys_template.php works, but i do not know why it shows anything.

The normal field from the template modul Setup works fine.

TYPO3 9.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file to `setup.txt`. I'm not sure if it's still the case in TYPO3 9.5, but in earlier versions the include only works with `.txt` file extensions.

Comment: .typoscript has been introduced with v8.7 (https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.7.x/Feature-78161-IntroduceTypoScriptFileExtension.html)

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. I think the problem was with the extension name in the sys_template.php

Thanks anyways