# setup.txt / setup.typoscript not being loaded in module

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm writing an extensio in Typo3 9.5 and I can't get the setup.txt or setup.typoscript to load.

I am trying to add a second page type that renders only JSON. For that I gather I need to change the typoscript. Therefore I added this code to my setup.typoscript:

```
ajax_ajaxjson = PAGE
ajax_ajaxjson {
    typeNum = 1

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = {
            10 {
                header = Content-Type: application/json
                replace = 1
            }
        }
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 1
        admPanel = 0
    }

    10 < tt_content.list.20.tx_energieportal_ajaxjson
}
```

*(in EXT:\Configuration\TypoScript\setup.txt)*

Now when trying to load that page type, I get the following error:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\ServiceUnavailableException
The page is not configured! [type=1][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=1 configured.
```

I also added a test variable, and when rendering that variable with

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="testvar"/>
```

I get the error:

```
No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "testvar"
```

I setup my sys_template.php up like this:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
    'energieportal',
    'Configuration/TypoScript',
    'Energieportal Frontend'
);
```

*(in EXT:\Configuration\TCA\sys_template.php).*

I also tried renaming the setup.txt to setup.typoscript.

Is there anything else I need to do to have my module load the setup.typoscript? I looked at the docs and other modules, but I couldn't find anything for setting up that file.

I used the search function, but the only similar question wasn't really answered. ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750393/typo3-setup-typoscript-configured-does-not-show-any-results))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the TCA of existing tables, you need to put the file into `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/`.

So, the correct path for your `sys_template.php` needs to be `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php`.

Comment: I put the file in Configuration\TCA\Overrides\sys_template.php and cleared the cache and the autoloading information. 
I can't see any difference, though. The type is still not available, and neither is the variable for the ViewHelper.
Is there anything else I need to do to import the sys_template.php?

Answer (score 0):

`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile` only adds it to the list of static TypoScript files which can be loaded in a TypoScript template. It does not load the TypoScript file automatically.

You will have to include it in a TypoScript template in the TYPO3 backend. You can find the available static templates in the `Includes` tab under `Include static (from extensions)`.

Alternatively you can include it in a different TypoScript file that is already loaded in the previously mentioned way using `@import 'EXT:EXT:energieportal/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript'` or `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:energieportal/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript">`

It is also possible to add TypoScript directly from PHP using `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScript('My TypoScript')`, so you can add the `@import` or `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT...>` line there. You can add this in your extension's `ext_localconf.php` or `Configuration\TCA\Overrides\sys_template.php`. It is however usually not recommended as you might not want the TypoScript loaded for all pages and/or sites in a TYPO3 installation.

Comment: That's good to know for opt-in typoscript. But I really need this file to automatically load always.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an option to automatically load it.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I added that function call to the ext_localconf.php and got the lines 
`[GLOBAL]
@import 'EXT:energieportal/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.text`
in my $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['defaultUserTSconfig']. 
But the file contents still do not load - no pagetype, no content for the viewhelper.
I'm really at my wit's end as to how to get typo to allow me to use another pagetype.
Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: Why are you using addUserTSConfig for loading TypoScript? Shouldn't you be using ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScript()?

Comment: The snippet in the question is written in TypoScript, not TSconfig. These are 2 different things, though they share the TypoScript syntax. Common source of confusion ...

Comment: see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Introduction/Index.html "Basically think of TypoScript as a means to “configure” the frontend, while TSconfig is used to configure the backend (with a few exceptions to this principle)"

Comment: You're right, I copy/pasted a bit to quickly. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work. The code is in the global $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE'] now, but that still has no effect on either the variable or the page types.

Comment: Does it work if you add the TypoScript manually? Did you check the TypoScript Object Browser to see if the TypoScript is included properly?